# How OrderBy afterwards HasMany and BelongsTo Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I created a relationship between the "Review, Games and Info" tables, unfortunately, though, the main table is Games, and he orders me all for Games, While I would like to order the ID of "review" table.

```
Models: Review
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Giochi', 'id_gioco', 'id');
    }
Models: Giochi
    public function review()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Review', 'id', 'id_gioco');
    }
    public function infogiochi()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\InfoGiochi', 'id', 'id_gioco');
    }
Models: InfoGiochi
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Giochi', 'id', 'id_gioco');
    }
Controller:
$review = Giochi::with('Review','InfoGiochi')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
```

Here is a screenshot of my json:

[image]

How do I order content for review table IDs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 options. You use a join and order in the sql statement or you order it after retrieving the results in the collection.

**Using Join**

```
Giochi::select('giocos.*')
    ->with('Review','InfoGiochi')
    ->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.id', '=', 'giocos.id_gioco')
    ->orderBy('reviews.id','DESC')
    ->get();
```

**Sorting Collection**

```
Giochi::with('Review','InfoGiochi')
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc(function($giochi) {
        return $giochi->review->id;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be the shortest version to sort on the collection:

```
Giochi::with('review')
->get()
->sortByDesc('review.id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your relationship query when you fire it:

```
Giochi::with([ 
     'Review' => function ($query) { return $query->orderBy('id','DESC'); },
     'InfoGiochi' 
])->orderBy('id','DESC');
```

Comment: @LegoLiam I've tested it on my machine and the query works correctly, how are you building that list of reviews?

Comment: The models are as I put them in the first message, I upload the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/cUW86iN.png), otherwise you do not understand the code here...

Comment: `Giochi` looks like it's a pivot table. If that's the case you shouldn't have a model for it. At any rate, maybe `orderBy('id_gioco','DESC')` would work for you instead of the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a **raw query** or you can use **->orderBy()** directly on review function.

Comment: I put `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Review', 'id', 'id_gioco')->orderBy('id','DESC')` but it does not work...